# Block elements overlapping with singularitygs

Tags: singularitygs

I'm doing my first project with singularity grid system and I'm loving it so far. However, I'm having a strange problem in a section where I have an `<h2>` and `<h3>` elements overlapping... really having an hard time figuring what's the problem.

My project in development is available at:
http://senseslabv3.brunomonteiro.mixture.io/

First `<section>` with `class=intro`.

Does anyone have a clue about it's going on?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you please provide HTML and SASS of the problematic section?

Answer (score 5):

As the others have said, you need to clear your floats. By default, Singularity's output style is "Isolation" which requires a knowledge of how floats should get cleared (`clear: left`, `clear: right`, `clear: both`, `clear: none`). Singularity assumes no clear (`clear: none`) which means that grid items may overlap if not properly cleared. It does this to adhere to the most common mental model for the Isolation output method, specifically placing blocks at a discrete point on the grid. Clearing your floats will clear them to an item's margin edge, most visibly by creating new rows. See the [Mozilla Developer Network article on Clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clear).

Note, clearing your floats and clearfixing as proposed by lolmaus actually do different things. Clearing your float will clear items to margin edges, whereas clearfixing an item will ensure that all of its floated children are properly contained.

The Float output adheres to a different mental model, one of walking across a row of your grid, and therefore automatically clears your floats for you. If you'd prefer to use the Float output style as your default, simply add `$output: 'float'` to your Sass file before calling your grid. This will change your global output style context. Alternatively, you can use `float-span` to use the Float output style mental model and output on-demand instead of `grid-span`, or pass `$output-style: 'float'` as an option to `grid-span`.

Take a look at the documentation for [Output Styles](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Output-Styles), [Output Span](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#output-span), [Float Span](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#float-span), and [Context Overrides in `grid-span`](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#context-overrides) for a deeper dive into the different output styles and options available in Singularity.

Answer (score 0):

Clear both needs to be declared somewhere below your grid-span mixin `.tag h3 {clear: both;}`

Comment: Hi Scott,

Adding the `clear:both` _after_ the `grid-span` seems to fix the problem but mess up the grid as you can see in the online version... probably because it anulates the `clear:none` used by singularity.

Strange it seems rather like a simple use case...
Any additional idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added an less elegant `div` with `clear:both` between the `h2`and `h3`. :|

Answer (score 0):

instead of the ugly `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` consider this:

```
.intro h2 {
  @include pie-clearfix; }
```

Or, if you use [toolkit](https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit):

```
.intro h2 {
  @extend %clearfix-micro; }
```

We might better address your problem if you share your SASS code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I just ran into the problem. Snugug's answer worked perfect but I wanted to show the code that worked for me. (Couldn't put code in a comment)

//Main content container

```
.l-main {  
  @include breakpoint(80em) {
    @include grid-span(16, 3, 20);  
  }  
}
```

// A full width banner inside content container. I needed this to clear because there are several other smaller columns/grids above and below the banner.

```
.b-banner {
  @include breakpoint(80em) {
    @include float-span(16, 1, last);
  }  
}
```