# Correct approach to clear row in singularitygs using isolation

Tags: singularitygs

I have a 2 column grid and two divs which I both want to span a single column starting in the first column. I want these to stack on top of each other but they are being overlayed on top of each other. Here is the scss:

```
#first {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  @include grid-span(1, 1);
}

#second {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  @include grid-span(1, 1);
}
```

I've fixed it by inserting an additional div between these two divs and using @include clearfix; or alternatively I can fix it by using @include isolate-span(2,1,'both'); on the second div.

Is there a more 'best practice' way of clearing a row like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283907/block-elements-overlapping-with-singularitygs/16304781#16304781), Singularity doesn't clear your floats for you when you're using Isolation output (`isolation` being when each float is isolated from one another's position, as opposed to `float` where they are not).

The short version of that answer is to use the CSS `clear` property, as explained very well in the [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fclear)